# Storybooking Hooks (as opposed to UI Components)

Tags: reactjs, storybook

I am using storybook to demo some react hooks, as opposed to UI components.
I am using MDX for the story format, example:

```
import { Meta, Story, Canvas } from '@storybook/addon-docs/blocks'
import { useRef } from 'react'
import useFullscreen from 'Hooks/use-fullscreen'

<Meta title="React Hooks/useFullscreen" />

## useFullscreen - react hook

export const FullscreenExample = () => {
  const ref = useRef()
  const { fullscreen, isFullscreen, exitFullscreen } = useFullscreen(ref)
  const style = { color: isFullscreen ? 'white' : 'inherit' }
  return (
    <div ref={ref} style={style}>
      <h1>Test FullScreen</h1>
      {!isFullscreen && <button onClick={fullscreen}>go fullScreen</button>}
      {isFullscreen && <button onClick={exitFullscreen}>exit fullScreen</button>}
    </div>
  )
}

<Canvas>
  <Story name="Default" parameters={{ layout: 'centered' }}>
    {FullscreenExample.bind({})}
  </Story>
</Canvas>
```

This gives me the desired result, as when i click on "Show code" it shows me the result of the templating but I would rather not have this template code in my MDX;
however, if i export it from somewhere else where i can reuse it (for testing or other stuff), like:

```
import { Meta, Story, Canvas } from '@storybook/addon-docs/blocks'
import FullscreenExample from './_examples'

<Canvas>
  <Story name="Default" parameters={{ layout: 'centered' }}>
    {FullscreenExample.bind({})}
  </Story>
</Canvas>
```

the `Show code` feature only shows me:

```
FullscreenExample.bind({})
```

I also tried:

```
import { Meta, Story, Canvas } from '@storybook/addon-docs/blocks'
import FullscreenExample from './_examples'

export const Example = (args) => <FullscreenExample {...args} />

<Canvas>
  <Story name="Default" parameters={{ layout: 'centered' }}>
    {Example.bind({})}
  </Story>
</Canvas>
```

and i get a similar result.

Is there a reasonable workaround for this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you can probably just invoke your example function as if it were a React component, like this:

```
<Canvas>
  <Story name="Default" parameters={{ layout: 'centered' }}>
    <FullScreenExample />
  </Story>
</Canvas>
```

Not sure about this as I don't use the `<Story>` wrapper for my examples. The other technique I use is to put the code into the `<Canvas>` as an IIFE, which looks ugly but has the advantage of showing the source code properly:

```
<Canvas>
  {(() => {
     const ref = useRef()
     const { fullscreen, isFullscreen, exitFullscreen } = useFullscreen(ref)
     const style = { color: isFullscreen ? 'white' : 'inherit' }
     return (
        <div ref={ref} style={style}>
           <h1>Test FullScreen</h1>
          {!isFullscreen && <button onClick={fullscreen}>go fullScreen</button>}
          {isFullscreen && <button onClick={exitFullscreen}>exit fullScreen</button>}
        </div>
     );
  })()}
</Canvas>
```

Comment: i actually like your solution and i don't find it ugly at all. am gonna test it when i have the chance. thx